# Floor behavior with number 1.9999999999999999d

Tags: c#, floor

Look at this situation:

```
var number1 = Math.Floor(1.9999999999999998d); // the result is 1
var number2 = Math.Floor(1.9999999999999999d); // the result is 2
```

In a both cases, the result should be 1. I know it's a very unlikely scenario, but possible to occur. The same ocurr with `Math.Truncate` method and `(int)` cast.

Why does it happen?

Comment: What happens if you just do, say, `Console.Write(1.9999999999999999d);`?

Comment: The problem here is that `1.9999999999999999d` is already `2`.

Comment: `1.9999999999999999d` can not be represented in the available bits, so it becomes `2.0d` in memory, which is then what `Floor()` receives as a parameter.

Comment: `Math.Floor(1.9999999999999999m)` is `1`, since a `decimal` has an exact representation for those digits. A `double` does not.

Comment: the precision of double is only 15-16 digits [see double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double). In your case it gets rounded up

Comment: And because all of that, there is Decimal,Floor(decimal d)...

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much for the answers!

Comment: also see [Floating Point in .NET part 1: Concepts and Formats](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/resources/Articles/FPDotNetConceptsAndFormats.aspx)

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact `double` representation for a lot of numbers.

The `double` number the nearest from `1.9999999999999999` is `2`, so the compiler rounds it up.

Try to print it before using your `Math.Floor` function !

However, the nearest from `1.9999999999999998` is still `1.something`, so `Floor` gives out `1` .

Again, it would be enough to print the number before the function `Floor`to see that they were actually not anymore the one entered in the code.

EDIT : To print out the number with most precision :

```
        double a1 = 1.9999999999999998;
        Console.WriteLine(a1.ToString("G17"));
        // output : 1.9999999999999998

        double a2 = 1.9999999999999999;
        Console.WriteLine(a2.ToString("G17"));
        // output : 2
```

Since double precision is not always precise to 17 significative digits (including the first one before the decimal point), default `ToString()` will round it up to 16 significant digits, thus, in this case, rounding it up to `2` as well, but only at runtime, not at compile time.

Comment: Printing does not help, as it won't give you the exact representation, e.g. for  `Console.WriteLine(1.999999999999999)`, I get `2`, yet flooring it yields `1`. `ToString("r")` might help, though, and shows that the number's internal representation is actually `1.9999999999999989`.

Answer (score -1):

If you put literals values into another variables, then you see it why:

```
var a1 = 1.9999999999999998d; // a1 = 1.9999999999999998d
var number1 = Math.Floor(a1);
Console.WriteLine(number1); // 1

var a2 = 1.9999999999999999d; // a2 = 2
var number2 = Math.Floor(a2);
Console.WriteLine(number2); // 2
```

As for why - this has to be *something* to do with [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12089817/1997232) of `double` and decision of compiler as to what value to use for a given literal.

Comment: At compile time, `1.9999999999999999d` is converted to the `double` with the exact value `2` (`1.9999999999999999d == 2.0d
` is `true`). After that, of course, the results are as expected.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, exactly, but why and how compiler does that -  no idea tbh. Why it didn't choose previous value?

Comment: What "previous value"? `2` is the nearest representible value, rounding upwards. Did you expect it to round downwards to `1.9999999999999998` instead? That would make little sense.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, *"rounding upwards"* - well, why upwards? Probably there are *reasons* behind that decision, but I am not able to answer on this question.

Comment: IEEE 754 and/or the C# language specification, something something. I can't find the relevant part of the specs that quickly, but the rules are out there... somewhere. (Not that the compiler necessarily follows them; in particular, the rules for `double` evaluation at compile time and at runtime are notoriously different, thanks to the extended 80-bit precision of the x87.)

Comment: It rounds using IEEE round-to-nearest which in picking between two equally precise possible values to round to it will pick that which has a 0 in the least significant bit (the other possibility will always have 1 there being 1 higher or lower in the mantissa). It's analogous to round-to-even ("bankers' rounding") in dealing with decimal numbers.